# A very simple JSON request with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to get a simple JSON request working with jQuery. I want to get the premiers of new shows from Trakt (API: http://trakt.tv/api-docs/calendar-premieres), but cannot navigate through the nodes. Seems that I might be needing a date attached after the API key in the URL, but I'm not sure, since dealing with JSON is quite new to me.

```
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: [url_with_actual_api_key],
      dataType: "json",
      async: true,
      cache: false,
      success: function(data){ 
        $.each(data, function(data, value) {
            $(".title").append("<div class='item'><span>Title:</span>" + value.title + "</div>");
        });
      }
```

I'm getting UNDEFINED of course, because I'm trying to retrieve data few levels 'deeper'. Also, value.episode shows nothing, getting the title is the closest I got. My question is, how do I get the whole data from the request for each episode on API's date?

Thanks a lot and a million highfives.

Comment: "but cannot navigate through the nodes" --- what does it mean?

Comment: So the `data` you get looks like the *Example Request* in the [linked API docs](http://trakt.tv/api-docs/calendar-premieres)? (or did you use a `date` parameter and they omitted the wrapper array?)

Comment: I didn't use a data parameter, because I'm note sure how to do it or do I actually need it. I don't get any data, except "undefined". When I use http://trakt.tv/api-docs/shows-trending for the URL with the same code (value.title) I can get the title. I'm kinda confused and lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate twice, since you have an array of `date`, containing an array of `episodes`:

```
success: function(data){ 
    // for each date
    $.each(data, function(index, broadcastDate) {

        // broadcastDate.date has the date
        // broadcastDate.episodes has the show data.

        $.each(broadcastDate.episodes, function(index,episode) {

          // episode contains show and episode objects

          $(".title").append("<div class='item'><span>Title:</span>" + episode.show.title + "</div>");
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be working. Also, the weird thing that only first couple of items are returned, not the whole data. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: I can't set this up and run it as I don't have the API key. I assume you have access to Firebug or Chrome developer tools. If so, check the incoming data, step through the code (it's possible there's something wrong with my function, or some unexpected condition is occurring), check that the output is going where you think it is. This is basic debugging stuff.